# OpenLayers 2: Can I delete vector layer or change its z-index when mouse hover on it?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am adding two vector layers.

```
this.mapport.vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
this.mapport.inside_vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
map.addLayer(this.mapport.vector);
map.addLayer(this.mapport.inside_vector);
```

and I am selecting features of inside_buffer like

```
inside_vector.setZIndex(999);
var inside_feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(inside_geom, null, this.inside_buffer_style);
this.mapport.inside_vector.addFeatures(inside_feature);
```

and vector layer 1 features as

```
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geom, null, this.buffer_style);
this.mapport.vector.addFeatures(feature);

this.request_select(feature, options, event, layers, behavior);
```

Initially I want to show user `inside_vector` layer but when user will hover over it Its z-index must be 0. Can I do it in OpenLayers 2?  till now I tried 4,5 examples on stack overflow but they are about features not about layer itself.

Comment: map.removeLayer() doesn't work?

Comment: And in braces I have to pass layer name ? @Chase Choi

Comment: No, it needs layer object itself.

Comment: @ChaseChoi   So how Can I do this on hover In my case ?

Comment: Do you have some fiddle to test ol2? if so i can give you the example quick

Comment: @ChaseChoi http://jsfiddle.net/DKBN6/6/

Comment: Although it is for union but I used it sepratelly both polygons.

Comment: umm, resources are not found.